# Change the text "search result for" on search result page

Tags: search, archives, title, text

I've been searching thru all WordPress files for the phrase "*search result for*", which is displayed on the search result page **(search result for (keywords))** but can't find it.

I would like it to be: "You searched for: (keywords)"

Does anybody know where and how to change this?

Comment: the string is with an 's' on results - 'search results for'. Looks like it's in the language files so could be edited there or with a child theme perhaps

Comment: This would depend entirely on how your theme is constructed. I suggest asking its author.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the following JavaScript in my theme:

```js
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  if (window.location.href.includes("?s=")) {

    // You might need to use adjust the archive title selector
    // according to the specific class of your header, for example:
    // const archiveTitle = document.querySelector(".elementor-heading-title");

    const archiveTitle = document.getElementByTagName('H1')[0];

    if (!!archiveTitle) {
      let text = archiveTitle.innerText;
      text = text.replace("Search Results For: ", "Resultados de la búsqueda de: ");
      archiveTitle.innerText = text;
    }
  }
});
```

This has disadvantage of creating FLUC (flash of un-styled content).

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', function($parts){
    if( is_search() ){
        $parts['title'] = sprintf('You searched for: %s',get_search_query());
    }
    return $parts;
});
```

Comment: well, WordPress didn't crash, but my text didn't change...

Comment: @JoBe how you search template file calls?

Comment: how do I do what?

Comment: What is name of search template file you using? Its your theme or you working with existing?

Comment: I'm using hello by elementor...